# What is the difference between storing the multi-dimensional arrays in memory in Row Major or Column Major fashion?

Tags: c, arrays

What is the difference between storing the multi-dimensional arrays in memory in Row Major or Column Major fashion?

As far as I know, 'C' seems to be following the Row Major style.

Just out of curiosity I would like to know, are there any benefits of one style over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can do emulate each one with the other, so there's no inherent advantage to one over the other. However, cache implementations usually consider locality of reference as a positive factor for estimating whether a memory location is going to get accessed soon. That may have performance implications. For instance, in a row-major implementation, this code snippet:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) 
     sum += a[i][j];
```

is likely to be faster than:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
     sum += a[j][i];
```

You should try to design your algorithms so that you code outer loops over rows in a row-major environment and over columns in a column major environment to minimize cache misses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wonder if there is no inherent advantage of one over another, then why different languages follow different styles?

Comment: @Jay: Some algorithms are better described in one way or the other. You can't make a general statement that one is strictly better than the other--and theoretically, you can always convert one style to the other by swapping the indexes. IMO, however, we usually write code that's better suited in a row-major implementation.

Comment: @Jay: Various representations may seem more natural for various problems. For matrices of numbers, it's (arguably) more natural to perceive them as "bunch of rows", rather then "bunch of columns", so you declare and store them in row-major order. Spatial data, on the other hand, use [x, y] indexing, where `x` is a column. For them, `data[x][y]` makes better reading, so it's better declared column-major.